# PHP - Would i need to create 2 separate objects to hold database data from 2 separate tables?

Tags: php, database, class, object

I may no be asking this questions right but here goes... I have a database with 2 tables "users" (for users name/password/etc) and "usersInfo" (users first name/last/address/etc). I only have 1 Users.php class- do i need 2 separate classes to create 2 objects from to hold the "users" & "usersInfo" data for the same user or will 1 class work (and still make 2 objects?)?

some of my Users.php class/

```
public function __construct($user = null) {
    $this->_db = DB::getInstance();

    $this->_sessionName = Config::get('session/session_name');
    $this->_cookieName = Config::get('remember/cookie_name');

    if(!$user) {
        if(Session::exists($this->_sessionName)) {
            $user = Session::get($this->_sessionName);

            if($this->find($user) || $this->findUserInfo($user)) {
                $this->_isLoggedIn = true;
            } else {
                //logout
            }
        }
    } else {
        $this->find($user);
        $this->findUserInfo($user);
    }

}
public function find($user = null) {
    if($user) {
        $field = (is_numeric($user)) ? 'id' : 'username';
        $data = $this->_db->get('users', array($field, '=', $user));

        if($data->count()) {
            $this->_data = $data->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}


public function findUserInfo($user = null) {

    if($user) {
        $test3 = $this->_db->get('users', array('username', '=', $user));
        $userId = $test3->first()->id;
        $data2 = $this->_db->get('usersInfo', array('user_id', '=', $userId));

        if($data2->count()) {
            $this->_userInfoData = $data2->first();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
public function data() {
    return $this->_data;
}

public function userInfoData() {
    return $this->_userInfoData;
}
```

Currently I have to create 2 objects to use all the data i need for the same user.

for example, in on of my pages.php i have:

```
$user = new User();
$user1 = new User($user->data()->username);

$userNane = $user->data()->username; //holds users username form "users" table
$userName1 = $user1->userInfoData()->first_name; // holds users first name from "usersInfo" table
```

It works but doesnt look right... is it efficient/ok practice/etc. If not, suggestions?

Also, first post, take it easy :)

Comment: Please note that normally, you should submit code review questions to... codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: No problem. Ask a mod to migrate your question if you want to get better input (I think my opinion is still very basic, and I just answered your main question, there are perhaps things to say about your code).

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between the 2 tables?
 1-1 ? 1-*? Can a user have multiple persona? Can a persona correspond to many user accounts? Will this relation change in the future?

Depending on your answers, you might see which solution fit better your plans.

- 1-1 relation: you can afford to have a single class to hold related records. It will be easier to manage from the perspective of your application
- Otherwise,  you'll need at one time or another to handle a record separately from related records in the other table. You'll be better off with 2 distincts objects.
- if you plan to change things later on for the second situation, you should keep things as they are.

In the specific case of user data, your comment bring the insight that certain data are more sensitive than others. In retrospect, I guess that's the reason you made these two tables separate. From that point of view, it is certainly better to keep both objects separate, even in a 1-1 relationship.

Regarding your code, indeed, having a dedicated `UserInfo` class, rather than piggy backing on another instance of `User`, would clearly be a good thing. A very important idea of good design is *separation of concerns*: you want each class to handle one and only one purpose, so that any modification to a class will have a limited scope of impact on the rest of the code.

As an example, the only thing you need to retreive a userinfo row, and therefore construct an object wrapping it, is the user id. Instead of delegating the whole job to a method of `User`, I would probably extract the iout of the `User` instance, and pass it to the adhoc `UserInfo` constructor or static method: there, each class only deals with things in its own perimeter. Of course, `findUserInfo` could also delegate to that same function.

Comment: I see. So, say a user visits their "profile" page for example, they would see data from both tables (1 to get just their username and other to get other data like name/address) but if another user wanted to view someone else's data or profile, they'd get only "userInfo" data from other user (but would get their own "user" data (to display their username)). If i did decide to make another class, say, UsersInfo.php, would it pretty much mimic the Users.php class for its methods (update,get, etc). AND if i didnt make another class, the way i have my findUserInfo method is OK(find users id)?

Comment: Most ORM (look up the term) provide a uniform interface to simple commands on table based objects. The term is CRUD (look up that one too). Then there is the layer which deals with services meaningful to your application (creating a new account, post message, etc). By separating these levels, you will also make things easier for you in the long run.

Comment: Now, *you* know exactly how these objects will be used in your apps, so it's up to you to design them appropriately, but keep in mind that simple, generic services (create, read, update, delete) as simple semantic building blocks will help you formulate higher level algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, on of the most important steps in designing/developing an app is creating a sound schema and model. Not sure how much database design experience you have, but you will want to read up on [First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) (1NF), and eventually (2NF and 3NF).

Part of the schema design stage is to identify all the nouns which you will reference in your app, in your case a `user` is a perfect example. Each of these identified nouns will then have attributes, which you will want to consider, in how each will be stored.

The problem in your situation is that you have `user` and `user_info`. As you stated `user` is for name, password, etc, whereas `user_info` is for `first_name`, `last_name`, `address` etc. Part of the design stage is to determine which of these attributes are **directly** attributable to the user object, and which are more ancillary in nature. Using your example: `name`, `password`, `first_name`, `last_name` are each directly attributable to the user noun (object), however address is more ancillary in nature, and there may be more than one address per user (billing address, vs physical address), so you may want to consider adding a `user_address` table. As you can see, by logically separating the attributes of the user noun (object), you start to identify relationships which make more sense (`user`, `user_address`) vs (`user`, `user_info`).

Once you identify the nouns, and separate their attributes, you can create your schema. From your schema you can use an Object Relational Mapper (ORM) like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), which will introspect your schema, and generate objects for you to use throughout your app. In your example you would end up with two objects; User and UserAddress. Also it's important that when developing your schema that you identify relationships between tables by implementing a foreign key constraints. For example, your `user_address` table should have a `user_id` column, which links to your `user` table. This way when doctrine introspects your schema, it will also identify these relationships, which makes coding much easier.

Once you have your ORM in place, you can then make code references like this:

```
// In your controller
$this->user = UserTable::findById($_SESSION['user_id']);

// Then in your view
Welcome <?php echo $user->getFirstName() ?>, to our wonderful app.

We have your addresses listed as follows:
<?php foreach ($user->getUserAddress() as $userAddress) ?>
<div>
    <?php echo $address->getStreet() ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Yes, it's a very simplistic example, but should properly demonstrate that if you design your schema properly, the code becomes semantic, which makes it easier to write, and maintain.